# Ruby Thin Client to listen for HTTP:Put, not sure where to start and what I need

Tags: ruby, http, thin, put, http-put

I have a python script that sends a file as a attachment with data vars over HTTP::PUT (can also be POST)

With POST I can grab it via PHP (on Apache) with one line of code (`echo file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);` )

but trying to do the same with ruby without Apache and PHP (not available to me) is having me look into Ruby script running on THIN. I've managed to create a thin script to listen on a port and respond with 200 OK, but can't find any example or read the API clearly to find out how I can capture PUT or POST data. Any code snippet or pointers apprecieated.

What I have so far:

```
require 'rack' 
process_requests = lambda { |env|
  response = []
  response << 200
  response << {"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}  
  body = ["Now What?"]  
  response << body
  return response
}

thin = Rack::Handler::Thin
thin.run process_requests
```

Output:

```
>> Thin web server (v1.5.0 codename Knife)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:8080, CTRL+C to stop
```

How I test it:

`curl --upload-file /tmp/testfile  http://localhost:8080`

Output:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    31    0     9  100    22      8     21  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--    21
Now What?
```

The file gets transferred apparently, but don't know how to grab it.

I can handle response headers and etc once I figure out how to check for and receive the file.

Thanks for any help,

Comment: Check out [the Rack specification](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/SPEC.html), specifically `rack.input`, or `env['rack.input']`, in your case.